# One chef client multiple chef servers

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef client (in windows) which already pointing to a chef server .Now we got a new chef server .Without disturbing the current setup , how can we make chef client point to both the chef servers?

Is it a good practice to make a chef client listen to multiple servers?

Comment: I'm unsure of why you would want to have a node report to two separate Chef servers. One of the strengths of Chef is you can have a Single Source of Truth for configuration. Having two Chef Servers manage the same node you will become vulnerable to strange and unexpected behavior, chief among them being differences in your Chef objects (data bags, cookbook versions, attributes, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply do this. If you would alter between the Chef Servers, you would likely end up in a big mess.

To migrate to a new Chef server, just include some cookbook which changes the URL in the chef-client config. Make sure to import all clients so that they can authenticate.

Comment: Thanks a lot StephenKing. Some are the suggestions are to create a separate windows service and manage to connect with both the CHEF servers. Is it possible to keep two Client.rb file and stay connected with  both the CHEF Servers? There is no One To Many connectivity concepts for Chef client and Chef server(s)?